# AngularJS routing: Ignore query parameters while routing

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This should be simple, but I am not finding the right solution anywhere.

```
// Routing file
    ...
    .when('/pathA', templateA)
    .when('/pathB', templateB)
    .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/lollz' });
```

Both paths have a bunch of optional query parameters. The pages work when there are no parameters, but every time I pass a parameter, the router lands on the page `/lollz`. How can I make the router ignore the query parameters and concentrate only on the sub-paths?

Comment: How are you passing the query parameters?

Comment: Sample uri :  /pathA?param1=1111

Comment: Could you create a fiddle for this?

Comment: Try `.when('/pathA:query', templateA)` to return the query parameters.

Comment: @georgeawg the issue is, I want to routing to ignore the query parameters, for the uri might not have any params and my application would still work...

Comment: Are you refusing to give it a try?

Comment: my bad, thought it doesn't change anything, for some reason, `/pathA?param1=aa` turns into `/pathA%3Fparam1=aa`, I understand that `%3F` is encoded form of `?`, but any idea why it happens with `'/pathA:query'` ?

Comment: @georgeawg located the issue, feeling stupid now, it was `$location.path` i was passing parameters with uri, when it should have been sent as seperate `.search` method

Comment: So by using `/pathA:query`, you were able to see that the question mark `?` had gotten mangled. I am glad that helped you debug the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was somewhere else, I made the mistake of passing query parameters to the `$location.path` like:

```
$location.path('/pathA?param1=aaa'); // which kept getting encoded into /pathA%3Fparams1=aaa
```

once I started passing the query params in chained `search` , the problem went away:

```
$location.path('/pathA').search({params1:'aaa'});
```